# Flex Localization: Could not find compiled resource bundle

Tags: apache-flex, localization

I tried every solution i found in the internet.

Im using flex 4.5, This is what im doing:

1. created directory locale/en_US in my src directory
2. add resources.properties file to that directory with some mappings.
3. add -locale en_US -source-path=./locale/{locale} -allow-source-path-overlap=true to the compile args.
4. checked in the framework that the en_US locale directory appear.
5. add metadata:

   ```
   <fx:Metadata>
        [ResourceBundle("resources")]
   </fx:Metadata>
   ```

starting the app gives me the exception:

```
Error: Could not find compiled resource bundle 'resources' for locale 'en_US'.
```

This is some of the main solutions i tried:

1. uncheck "Remove unused RSLs" from the build path.
2. add the directory as a source path.
3. using the argument -include-resource-bundles and give my directory here (with using the argument -resource-bundle-list to get all bundles).

Any idea what else can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found a solution here:

http://www.nbilyk.com/flex-localization-example

im really not sure why it should be that difficult.

anyway, if someone ever need a help with that. after you successfully compile the file using ant (like described in the link), if you want to load it dynamcally like i needed just use (for example):

```
resourceManager.localeChain = ["en_US", "es_ES"];
resourceManager.loadResourceModule("Resources_en_US.swf");
resourceManager.loadResourceModule("Resources_es_ES.swf");
```

worked well for me, no need to add anything to the compiler args for that solution.

Comment: Ahh I see… you neglected to mention that you were trying to compile the resource bundles themselves into a swf. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: Thanks, i actully didnt try to compile the resources themselves but this is the only way i got around it, so as long it works well im happy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fully qualified directory path name.  If you're using ant you can use `${basedir}/src/locale/{locale}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried to do that as well with no luck. if im giving a wrong path im getting an error anyway, so this part was covered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my structure for [a mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.de.preferans) (Android and iOS):

In `src/locale` I have 3 subdirs: `de_DE`, `en_US`, `ru_RU`

And in compiler options: `-locale=ru_RU,en_US,de_DE -source-path=locale/{locale}`

For another mobile app I have:

In `src/locale` 4 subdirs: `en_US`, `hr_HR`, `sr_RS`, `sl_SI`.

I had to add the latter 3 dirs with [copylocale](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f2d.html) command.

And in compiler options: `-locale hr_HR sr_RS sl_SI en_US -allow-source-path-overlap=true`

Both apps work well for me with the latest [Apache Flex SDK](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html).

Here is the contents of a *src/locale/hr_HR/recources.properties* file:

```
# resources.properties file for locale hr_HR

navbar.tables=Stolovi za igranje:
navbar.all=Svi
navbar.vacant_long=Slobodni
navbar.vacant_short=Slb.
navbar.full_long=Su puni
navbar.full_short=Su puni

comments.good_long=dobri
comments.good_short=Dbr.
comments.bad_long=loši
comments.bad_short=loši
comments.without_long=neutralni
comments.without_short=ntr.

help.title=Pomoć
```

Comment: I did exactly that but i didnt use the apache flex sdk but adove flex 4.5 sdk, do you think there might be a problem here?

Comment: It is so easy to install the new Apache Flex SDK using their [installer](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html), that you ought to try it out :-)